# Adobe AEM 6.3 - Creating a Project with LazyBones - Missing acs-commons errors

Tags: java, jsp, adobe, lazybones

I am following the tutorial here: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem_lazybones.html

The errors are encountered when I follow the step listed here: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem_lazybones.html#ImporttheLazybonesprojectintoEclipse to import the lazybones project into Eclipse.

When I create a new project, I see 2 errors, both notifying me that a jsp file is missing. I cannot find any information on why the acs-commons is missing from the project, or how I can correct these errors.

Fragment "/apps/acs-commons/components/utilities/errorpagehandler/default.jsp" was not found at expected path /example-project.ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/acs-commons/components/utilities/errorpagehandler/default.jsp default.jsp /example-project.ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler  line 2  JSP Problem

Fragment "/apps/acs-commons/components/utilities/errorpagehandler/404.jsp" was not found at expected path /example-project.ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/acs-commons/components/utilities/errorpagehandler/404.jsp 404.jsp /example-project.ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler  line 2  JSP Problem

Note -- I am a front-end web developer attempting to create a new project for prototype template and component testing. I am utilizing the Eclipse IDE and JDK version 1.8, as listed in the page prerequisites.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently, you have to read the note provided at the bottom of this step. Once you delete the two files (404.jsp and default.jsp) from "ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler", the errors go away.

[image: Note for Lazybones import to Eclipse]